# WMI error. RPC Server not available

Tags: wmi, dcom, wmic

I know this is similar to a lot of questions on here, but I feel it's worth a new question since I have yet to discover a question that fully encompasses my problem. I've been struggling with this for a couple weeks, read pretty much every answer to every question about it on here, as well as countless blogs, articles and other Q&A forums. So, here goes:

I created a service to monitor several things on our network and update a database with the information. Moved it to a server and went threw a lot of frustration with getting the WMI and DCOM settings right so that it would work.
I recently had my computer crash on me and so I lost my code and had to recreate the service from scratch/memory. It runs perfectly fine on my laptop. I moved it to a server(different than the one that is running the old version of the service). It runs there, but it is unable to reach the PCs I am monitoring. I try running the command line WMI query and can't connect there either. Getting the 'RPC Server is unavailable' error.

I've tried changing settings as per all of the articles/answers I've been able to find and cannot get it to connect.

A few relevant things:

- All the RPC/WMI related services are running on both server and
  monitored PCs.
- The firewall is disabled on both server and monitored PCs.
- I know the user and password are correct and have admin rights
  on monitored PCs.
- Server in question is (I believe, will confirm with someone later)
  Windows Server 2008 R2 on a virtual server, if that makes a
  difference.
- Able to ping PCs and run tracert from server.

Here's where it doesn't make sense to me. I am able to run the wmic command from my laptop to the monitored PC. And from my laptop to the server. Wmic works locally on the server, but whenever I try to make a remote call, it fails with the RPC error.

I don't know much about networking, and we are a small company so we don't really have a Network Admin or anything. So, any and all advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and paste here a few sample failing `WMIC` commands (including returned error message), e.g. `WMIC /node:pcname process`. If `ping -4 pcname` works and returns `pc_ip`, then what about `WMIC /node:pc_ip process`? What about `WMIC /node:localhost process`? The `RPC Server is unavailable` error could be simply a keying mistake in `pcname`. Did you `ipconfig /flushdns` succesfully?

Comment: It's any of the wmic commands that I try. I use the ip to connect, not the pc name. Also, am able to ping and tracert from server to pc. Will try flushing dns.

Comment: I recollected right now (seeing your _I use the ip to connect_): `arp -d *` could be useful !!!